# Any way a javascript in a html file with file:// origin can load a json file data?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a html report that supposed to load from local disk. Like `c:\report\index.html`.

The local directory include the following files:

```
c:\report\index.html
c:\report\data.json
```

I am trying to have javascripts in the html file load the `data.json` mentioned above, use `JSON.parse`. Every techniques I use I get the error complains that the CORS policy forbids to load a json file from `file://` even though I am trying to load it from the same directory location of the html file.

I am hoping I don't have to give up on this approach since the result would be beneficial. A simple report.html renders a sophisticated json data without the needs of any additional program or tool. Just an existing chrome browser.

Is there any possible to do this task?

Comment: What is the code you are using right now?

Comment: Not possible with a browser. Install a server and use it instead of the local file system.

Comment: @Teemu, I know a it is easy with http(s) origin. I wanted to make every effort to make it working with file:// origin.

Comment: @Teemu, if you are confident this is not possible, perhaps it should be marked as the answer